# Am I correctly getting the label text?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some JS that reads an asp label's text and based on that sets a div visible or not.

```
 function setToLabel() {
        text = document.getElementById('add_view');
        lbl = document.getElementById('lblAddVisible');
        var isHidden = text.innerText == 'true';
        text.style.display = isHidden ? 'block' : 'none';
    }

    $(document).ready
(
     function()
     {
         setToLabel();
     }

);
```

The problem is it only works if I explicitly set the isHidden variable. When I tell it to read the label to get the bool, it does not ever work.

Thanks

Comment: `alert("Inner text: " + text.innerText)`. What do you see?

Comment: With a pic like that @user2043533 how do I know you're not one of the trolls? :-P JK

Comment: Have you looked at it in the debugger?

Comment: Are you posting back to the server and losing the value?  Please show the html.

Answer (score 2):

That's because when the control is rendered ASP gives the control a distinct ID from the one you've specified. If the script is rendered on the same page as your ASP code you can add this

```
lbl = document.getElementById('<%= lblAddVisible.ClientID %>');
```

otherwise you'll have to add a `CssClass` to the `lblAddVisible` control and get the element by class name. Also, make sure you are using the correct element that you need to read the innerHTML from.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having nested controls in your aspx page, it might be that you are not using the correct Id. Try this:

```
text = document.getElementById('<%=add_view.ClientID%>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function setToLabel() {
    text = document.getElementById('add_view');
    lbl = document.getElementById('lblAddVisible');
    var isHidden = lbl .innerText;
    text.style.display = isHidden ? 'block' : 'none';
 }

 $(document).ready
 (
 function()
 {
     setToLabel();
 }

 );
```

instead of `txt.innerText` ,you need to use `lbl.innerText` as you have to read from label